# java dependency injection (setter methods injection)

Tags: java, spring, constructor, dependency-injection, getter-setter

I am trying to understand dependency injection before learning how to use Spring. My question is that in the following example of Setter-based Dependency Injection, why is there no constructor for the TextEditor class? Do we not need a constructor here? Many thanks for your help!!

( code sourced from: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/setter_based_dependency_injection.htm)

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class TextEditor {
   private SpellChecker spellChecker; //Q: Why not a constructor for TextEditor, but only a class variable? 

 // a setter method to inject the dependency.
  public void setSpellChecker(SpellChecker spellChecker) {

    System.out.println("Inside setSpellChecker." );
    this.spellChecker = spellChecker;

 }
// a getter method to return spellChecker
  public SpellChecker getSpellChecker() {
     return spellChecker;
  }

  public void spellCheck() {
    spellChecker.checkSpelling();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't declare a constructor explicitly, a default no-arg public constructor is added automatically. From the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html),

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. 
>   The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without 
>   constructors.

And this constructor will be used by the Spring container to instantiate the object.